# Create a new file every time a TCL script runs

Tags: tcl, expect, logfile

I am new to TCL and got some stuff I need to automate and I need my code to log all the commands and results after the login process. 
My main issue is that I need to create a distinct log file everytime I run the script and one way I found out was to "append" the unique "timestamp" to the file name.

Here is where it starts to get picky, you see, every time I try to append the variable "$time" to the filename it returns:
couldn't open "15-10-28/11:57:10--xxx.xxxx.xxxx.txt": no such file or directory
    while executing
"log_file "$newfile" "
    (file "ssh-test.tcl" line 31)

My code is as follows:

```
set user [lrange $argv 0 0]
set password [lrange $argv 1 1] 
set ipaddr [lrange $argv 2 2]   
set arg1 [lrange $argv 3 3] 
set systemTime [clock seconds]
set time [clock format $systemTime -format %y-%m-%d/%H:%M:%S--]
set a "ssh"
set suffix ".txt"
append newfile "${a}${arg1}${suffix}"

set timeout -1   
# now connect to remote UNIX box (ipaddr) with given script to execute

spawn ssh $user@$ipaddr
match_max 100000
# Look for passwod prompt
expect "*?assword:*"
# Send password aka $password 
send -- "$password\r"
log_file "$newfile" ;
expect "*#"
send -- "\r"
send_user "This is the $argv0 Script"
send -- "scm $arg1\r"
expect "*#"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

If I use the 'set filename "${a}${arg1}${suffix}"' string and 'log_file "$filename"' it works just fine but it will append the new info to the already existing file and I want a new file everytime I run the script.

If I use the 'append newfile "${a}${arg1}${suffix}"' string and 'log_file "$newfile"' it won't work and return the error already referred.

Hope you guys can help me out and thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the timestamp with `/` in it.

```
set time [clock format $systemTime -format %y-%m-%d/%H:%M:%S--]
```

While appending this to the variable `newfile`, it will become `15-10-28/11:57:10--xxx.xxxx.xxxx.txt`.

Expect will think that there is a folder called `15-10-28` available and under which I have to create the file `11:57:10--xxx.xxxx.xxxx.txt`. Since that folder is not available, you are getting the error message as  `no such file or directory`

Comment: I tried to correct that and still got the error, this is the changed code:

set time [clock format $systemTime -format %y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S]
set a "ssh-"
set suffix ".txt"
#append newfile "${a}${arg1}${time}${suffix}"

Comment: nope, now it is:

'couldn't open "ssh-xxxx.xxxx.xxxx15-10-2813:53:41.txt": protocol error
    while executing
"log_file "$newfile" "
    (file "ssh-test.tcl" line 31)'

Answer (score 0):

After figuring out that the date format was messing up my code, I started playing around with the special characters and got it working like this:

```
set time [clock format $systemTime -format %a_%b_%d_%Y@%H'%M'%S]
```

It is not the desired format but at least I got it working as I intended.